# Problem trying to load odbcad32 on 64-bit machine

Tags: java, odbc

I am currently making a small java application to do some CRUD on an access database. At tafe they run 32-bit machines so it works there, but at home i run 64-bit so i did some research and found out about the odbcad32.exe in SysWOW64. So i made the data source there and J Creator still has an error that says The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application. So im now thinking that even though the dsn is in the 32-bit version, J Creator is still looking in the 64-bit version.

here is the .properties file that the ap loads.

```
driver = sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
url = jdbc:odbc:booksDSN_32;database=booksdb.mdb
username = user
password = password
connections=1
```

I thought maybe the url needs to be different so i changed it to

url = jdbc:odbcad32:booksDSN_32;database=booksdb.mdb

no luck with that. i'm sure its something small im missing here

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: for some more information i looked in project settings and under the JDK Profiles it is using JDK version 1.6.0_24 which appeares to be in program files\java

Comment: that looks to me to be 64-bit Java.  What happens if you change it to 32-bit Java?

Comment: Sorry but i dont know how to change it to 32-bit. is it just creating a new JDK Profile with a home path of program files (x86)\java?

Comment: I believe so, although I've not used JCreator extensively.  JCreator will ask you for a home path for the JDK.  That should be something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_NN`.

Comment: ok looks like ill have to go and instal the 32-bit version because in program files (x86)\java the is only a folder jre6

Comment: Yes its worked. i needed to be running 32-bit Java for J Creator to look in odbcad32.exe Thank you for taking it slow for me Luke!!!!

Comment: That's okay Zac, glad to know you sorted it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit Java?

In other words, on your 64-bit machine, is Java running from somewhere under `C:\Program Files\Java` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`?

I've had a couple of issues in the past with using 32-bit DLLs with Java on 64-bit machines.  The fix in both cases was to use 32-bit Java.

Comment: i have a java file in both program files and program files (x86). im not sure how to tell which one it uses.

Comment: In JCreator, choose the Project Settings item from the Project menu.  In the JDK Profiles tab, one of the JDK profiles should be ticked.  Click on it and click Edit.  Does the 'Home path' contain `C:\Program Files\Java` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`?

Answer (score 0):

Tall and short is ---

- All executables, dlls, etc running the same process space all have to be the same bitness (either all 32bit or all 64bit)
- The Sun JDBC to ODBC Bridge will have a C part (the ODBC bit) that will *probably* be 32bit..

So, you will *need* to run your Java program using a 32bit Java Runtime Environment - that loads the 32bit C part of the Bridge - that looks in the Registry for a 32bit ODBC Data Source - that loads a 32bit ODBC Driver...

I suspect that what you have is - 64bit Java failing to load 32bit C part of the bridge...

There are other JDBC to ODBC Bridges available like the [Multi-tier JDBC to ODBC Bridge](http://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-mt/) from [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com) which is built using a client/server architecture.

Thin JDBC client connecting to and ODBC Bridge server side (or same machine as client) - which can be pretty useful where an ODBC Driver exists in a certain bitness (say, 32bit only)...